# How to determine the appropriate MOV instruction suffix based on the operands?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

[image]

The answer is 
1. movl
2. movw
3. movb
4. movb
5. movq
6. movw

But how do we determine that?

Comment: All of these movs have a register operand that forces a particular size

Comment: 32-bit version with mostly the same instructions: [Chosing suffix (l-b-w) for mov instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20247944)

Answer (score 1):

Simply look at the destination operand and specify its size.

Case 1 : You are moving the value at address specified by register `rsp` to the register eax. Therefore, you should use `movl` which means move a long value. This is done because the eax register is 4 bytes wide which make up a long.

The same applies to the other cases.

- movb - move byte.
- movw - move word (2 bytes).

Comment: This is true, although as harold points out GNU assembler doesn't require any instruction suffixes in the cases presented in the OPs question because it will look at the operands to see if the size can be implied. One situation where the assembler can't make such a determination is for something like `mov $0xff, (%rcx)` . It doesn't know how many bytes need to be written to memory location pointed to by RCX. Is 0xff a byte, word, dword? You have to be explicit by using `movb $0xff, (%rcx)`, `movw $0xff, (%rcx)`, `movl $0xff, (%rcx)` etc.

Comment: Your rule fails for the last case: storing a register to memory.  The operand-size can be implied by either operand for pretty much any instruction (except `movzx` / `movsx`, aka AT&T `movzw` / `movzb` / etc where only the destination can imply the operand size, because the source can have a different size.  e.g. `movswl (%rax), %ecx` can be written as `movsw (%rax), %ecx`)

Comment: > *You are moving the value at address specified by register rsp to the register eax.* It is the other way around. rsp is the dest, and eax is source.

Comment: Same question here, with a better answer imo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248163/2279422